# Spring HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE not always set

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Curious if someone can share some feedback on why a HttpServletRequest may not have specific attributes set from the Spring Framework. We are using the attribute keyed off of HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html)

The example code is within a OncePerRequestFilter.doFilterInternal() after calling the chain.

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    String path = (new UrlPathHelper()).getPathWithinApplication(request);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    String scrubbedPath = scrubPath(request, path);
}

private String scrubPath(HttpServletRequest request, String path) {
    String message = "Response Metric Info";
    String scrubbedPath = path;
    Object bestMatchingPattern = request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE);
    if (bestMatchingPattern != null) {
        //This changes path from .../collection/{alias} to ../collection/alias
        scrubbedPath = fixSpecialCharacters(bestMatchingPattern.toString());
    } else {
        // this is temporary to help with understanding why we get multiple metric names for the same path
        message = "BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE null";
    }

    logHandlerInfo(message, request, path);

    return scrubbedPath;
}

// temp helper method to understand why some metrics are being formatted differently for the same path
// causing multiple metrics for the same path
private void logHandlerInfo(String message, HttpServletRequest request, String path) {
    final String LINE_SEPARATOR = System.lineSeparator();
    StringBuilder metricInfoBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    metricInfoBuilder.append(message);
    metricInfoBuilder.append(LINE_SEPARATOR).append(String.format("Input Path=%s", path));
    metricInfoBuilder.append(LINE_SEPARATOR).append(String.format("HandlerMapping.Path=%s", request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE)));
    metricInfoBuilder.append(LINE_SEPARATOR).append(String.format("HandlerMapping.Best=%s", request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)));
    metricInfoBuilder.append(LINE_SEPARATOR).append(String.format("HandlerMapping.Introspect=%s", request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.INTROSPECT_TYPE_LEVEL_MAPPING)));
    metricInfoBuilder.append(LINE_SEPARATOR).append(String.format("HandlerMapping.UriTemplate=%s", request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE)));
    metricInfoBuilder.append(LINE_SEPARATOR).append(String.format("HandlerMapping.Matrix=%s", request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.MATRIX_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE)));
    metricInfoBuilder.append(LINE_SEPARATOR).append(String.format("HandlerMapping.MediaTypes=%s", request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PRODUCIBLE_MEDIA_TYPES_ATTRIBUTE)));
    log.info(metricInfoBuilder.toString());
}
```

Here is the sample logs.

```
2018-10-08 20:51:58:300 [qtp1346560976-53746897] []  INFO  c.e.m.e.metrics.MetricsFilter - Response Metric Info
Input Path=/v1/group/test/collection/test-dev/status
HandlerMapping.Path=/v1/group/test/collection/test-dev/status
HandlerMapping.Best=/v1/group/{groupAlias}/collection/{alias}/status
HandlerMapping.Introspect=null
HandlerMapping.UriTemplate={groupAlias=test, alias=test-dev}

2018-10-08 20:46:57:745 [qtp1346560976-53746897] []  INFO  c.e.m.e.metrics.MetricsFilter - BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE null
Input Path=/v1/group/test/collection/test-dev/status
HandlerMapping.Path=null
HandlerMapping.Best=null
HandlerMapping.Introspect=null
HandlerMapping.UriTemplate=null
```

Comment: Do the different outputs happen seemingly randomly from what you observed? Or they are the results of different manipulationsÉ

Comment: Random. Have been trying to find a pattern but one call will have the argument while another call doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are set by the HandlerMapping that finds a matching handler for the request. As the Javadoc indicates, not all HandlerMapping implementations are required to do so but AbstractUrlHandlerMapping and RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping do which covers the built-in implementations.

For the attributes to be missing they are either not added, or are later removed, both of which seem unlikely. To debug further I suggest first finding out which HandlerMapping is used for the specific request, for example by setting the log level for org.springframework.web to DEBUG. That will tell you if the mapping supports adding those attributes or not. If it is a sub-class of one of the ones mentioned above, then it should be adding them.

You can also find the places in the code where the attributes are set and put a breakpoint to see what happens. Assuming you find out the attributes do get added, then you could debug to see if they get removed for some reason.